# Does Yoda know the contents of the sacred Jedi texts?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, yoda

After burning the Force tree in front of Luke, our little green friend says the following about the sacred Jedi texts:

> Read them, have you? Page-turners, they were not.

**How does Yoda know that those books are not page-turners?**

- Had he read them before dying? (and if so, how?)
- Can he "read" them through the Force while being dead?
- Is he just joking and has no idea what's inside them?

Comment: Assuming they're like a manual for the force they're not going to be particularity gripping. Also I think Luke refers to them as the original Jedi texts meaning there were likely copies.

Comment: It struck me that these are *copies of the original Jedi writings*  rather than *the literal originals*  (paper + moist sea air + 1000 years = mulch). As such, there would likely have been other copies available in the Jedi temples and Yoda would have had an opportunity to study them.

Comment: @Valorum - likely. Plus, he probably chats with other Force Ghosts.

Comment: @Valorum they were stored in a place of great power. I think it's reasonable to assume the force could keep a few books dry. Which is not to say other copies didn't exist, I'm sure they did, only that those could actually have been the original manuscripts.

Comment: @terdon - That's not how the Force works.

Comment: I'm sure you know more about this than I do, but I really don't see why not. The force does keep practitioners young for longer, why couldn't it be used to keep manuscripts? And the presence of caretakers on the island suggests it wasn't just abandoned to the ravishes of time. They would have protected the manuscripts in one way or another. Perhaps not by using the force but somehow.

Comment: I'm expecting that Rey took them and will have them in EP IX.

Comment: @enderland - At the end of the movie, Finn gets something out of a drawer inside the Millennium Falcon.  On the other end of the drawer, you can briefly see something that looks like the spine of one of the old books.

Comment: @Valorum The visual dictionary contains the following quote “Luke’s travels have allowed him to collect and assemble ancient scriptures containing lost Jedi wisdom and abilities. Actual books such as these are a true primitive rarity.” The implication being that these haven’t always been on the island and appear to be originals or at least very old.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Old, sure. My bible is five hundred years old. That doesn't make it an original :-)

Comment: @Valorum I agree was just pointing out that the book contradicts your paper + moist sea air + 1000 years comment.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - That was my point. It must have been somewhere else (somewhere dry) for it to have survived that long. These could (theoretically) have been the originals but that seems unlikely.

Comment: "Read them, have I? Wrote them, I did! Boring, they are...an editor I needed."

Comment: Why don't you think those sacred texts weren't digitized in Jedi Archives?

Comment: Who says they were written on mundane paper? I'm sure the Star Wars galaxy has the technology to make booklike material that can survive Scottish weather for millennia.

Comment: I want to write an answer but I don't have any more information than anyone else, but from the discussion here it seems that if the library is of Sacred Jedi Texts then of course the great Jedi Master Yoda would know it, and if Luke just found this library, then it wouldn't be a Sacred Jedi Text. Yoda knew about the contents of the library (boring), ergo they must be books he knows about.

Comment: All the comments on this post are fairly interesting but they are all assumptions. I am looking for a canon, official answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yoda was a Jedi Master for over 800 years and had access to what is most likely the most comprehensive library in the galaxy. I say the odds are high that 1) The Jedi library had a copy of the texts (if not the originals themselves) and 2) at some point in his 800 years as a Master he found time to read them at least once.

Indeed for all we know they're required reading for padawans!